# -bash:react-native: command not found ...i wanna know how to add path mac terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

.
I was recently developing react-native with expo.
I've got a real-native-cli thing to do.
It was installed according to the description of the Internet.
However, this error occurs in my pulse.

```
-bash:react-native: command not found
```

So I looked for the Internet to solve this error again, but...
I don't know how to add a path.

If I type `npm install -g react-native-cli,`

It says...

```
/Users/bong/npm-global/bin/react-native -> Users/bong/npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
```

Teachers... please solve my problem..
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/Users/bong/npm-global/bin/` path should be included in the PATH, this can be achieved by placing it in the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file. This can be achieved by running the following command:

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/Users/bong/npm-global/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: thank u so much!! 
thanks to ur help, i solve the problem